# Most efficient way to store application logs in searchable form on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging

I manage the AWS-hosted backend for a mobile app startup, and historically we have stored application log data (i.e. raw API requests) in InnoDB tables on our production MariaDB instance on RDS. This log data isn't used by our application; we only use it for debugging and statistics, and we truncate the tables every 1-2 days.

As our activity has grown, I've found that this has been increasingly inefficient, as our prod DB gets hit heavily by logging queries and the log tables have gone from 100k rows a day to 2M+.

What is the best way to store logs like this (preferably using AWS) in a manner that remains searchable?

Comment: elasticsearch via graylog and/or logstash.

Answer (score 4):

Suggest you look into using [Cloudwatch Logs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/07/10/introducing-amazon-cloudwatch-logs/). Logs are kept indefinitely by default, you can search them, you can alert on anything you like. You can move them to any other AWS service, like EMR, to do further analysis.